# how to return an array with integers multiplied by 3 in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I think my problem could be that my value of **i** and the value of **start** are the same... so my loop stops too early. To tackle that problem I tried setting: "while (i < length)" to "while (i < length + start)" I did this to add back the value of the start parameter but my output doesn't change.

```
function triple_sequence(start, length) {

    var res = [start];
    var i = start;
    while (i < length) {
        i *= 3;    
        res.push(i);
        i++;
    }
    return res;
}

console.log(triple_sequence(2, 4));
//[2, 6, 18, 54]
```

Comment: Omit the `i *= 3`, instead do `res.push(start * 3 ** i)`

Comment: `i *= 3`will multiply `i` by `3` *and set `i` to the result*.

Comment: So you want [start, start*3, start*3*3, ..., start*3^(length-1)].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're checking `i` rather than the length of the result. Change

```
while (i < length)
```

to

```
while (res.length < length)
```

Also, don't put `i++` in the loop. You're already updating `i` with `i *= 3;`.

Answer (score 1):

You are confuse by using an index variable `i` and the use as value for the array.

You could check the length of the array with the wanted length and use a `value` variable for multiplying.

This value need no increment later.

```js
function triple_sequence(start, length) {
    var res = [start],
        value = start;

    while (res.length < length) {
        value *= 3;
        res.push(value);
    }
    return res;
}

console.log(triple_sequence(2, 4)); // [2, 6, 18, 54]
```

A shorter approach

```js
function triple_sequence(start, length) {
    return Array.from({ length }, (_, i) => start * 3 ** i);
}

console.log(triple_sequence(2, 4)); // [2, 6, 18, 54]
```

Comment: Can be even shorter with an arrow function!

Answer (score 0):

There were a couple of mistakes in your code, the most severe one being that you both multiplied i by 3 and incrementing it. This code works better:

```
function triple_sequence(start, length) {

    var res = [start];
    var i = start;
    while (i < length) {
        i++;
        res.push(i * 3);

    }
    return res;
} 

triple_sequence3(0, 3); // [0, 3, 6, 9]
```

Comment: This will return `[2, 9, 12]`, not the desired result.

Comment: Ok, then I misunderstood the question. I thought he needs multiples of 3